# i want to set the width of cells of table header dynamically at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am creating an HTML Markup , and i have two tables , one is only table header places on a div , and another div below it contains another table that should display the details of that header . i mean the header and the details are separated in two tables for the business requirements sake.

the problem is that i can't make the right alignment , of the columns , i mean the header of the table is not aligned to the columns of the details table ,

i want to know a simple idea to implement this , as i tried to get the width of the details column in the runtime and set it on the table column header , but this does't work ,

here below i am listing the HTML markup. you will fin the table header on a div called header2 and the details is on a div called content.

any help please

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style>

    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    li {
        padding-left: 0.5em;
    }
  .handle {                                                                            
  background-repeat: no-repeat;                                            
  background-position: center bottom;                                      
  display: block;                                                          
  float: left;                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                    
  .collapsed {                                                                         
  /*background: transparent url(/images/plus-black.png);*/                     
  background-repeat: no-repeat;                                            
  background-position: center bottom;                                      
  cursor: pointer;                                                         
}                                                                           
  .expanded {                                                                          
  /*background: transparent url(/images/minus-black.png);*/                    
  background-repeat: no-repeat;                                            
  background-position: center bottom;                                      
  cursor: pointer;                                                         
}   
  #header {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%
  }
  #header2 
  {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top:13%;
   /*/*padding-left:1.5%*/*/
   }
  #content {
   margin-top: 19%;
   position:absolute;
   width: 100%;
   overflow-y:auto;
   height:30%;
}
  input[type=checkbox] {
 float:left;
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="treeview.min.css" />
<script src="treeview.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv(x) {
        
        document.getElementById('div'+x).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('td'+x).style.backgroundColor = "cadetblue";
        togglecheckboxes('cbgroup5');
        var width = document.getElementById('div' + x).offsetWidth;
        ExpandColumnWidth(width, 5);

        
    }
    function HideDialog(x) {
        document.getElementById('div' + x).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById('td' + x).style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        document.getElementById('tdd' + x).style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        document.getElementById('tddd' + x).style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
    function ExpandAll()
    {
        jQuery("#tree ul").show();
        debugger;
        var x = document.getElementById("tst1").style.width;
    }
    function CollapseAll()
    {
        jQuery("#tree ul").hide();
    }
    function togglecheckboxes(group)
    {
        var cbarray = document.getElementsByClassName(group);
        for (var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++) {
            var cb = document.getElementById(cbarray[i].id);
            cb.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
    function ExpandColumnWidth(width,group)
    {
        var tbarray = document.getElementsByClassName("td"+group);
        for (var i = 0; i < tbarray.length; i++) {
            var tb = document.getElementById(tbarray[i].id);
            tb.style.width = width+'px';
        }
    }

    //$(document).ready(function () { var w = document.getElementById() });

$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#tree ul").show();

  jQuery("#tree li").each(function() {
    var handleSpan = jQuery("<span></span>");
    handleSpan.addClass("handle");
    handleSpan.prependTo(this);

    if(jQuery(this).has("ul").size() > 0) {
      handleSpan.addClass("collapsed");
      handleSpan.click(function() {
        var clicked = jQuery(this);
        clicked.toggleClass("collapsed expanded");
        clicked.siblings("ul").toggle();
      });
    }
  });

  
  
})

    
//})
</script>    
<div id="header" style="overflow:auto"  >
        <h1></h1>
        <div class="class=" col-lg-7">
            <p class="bs-component">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ExpandAll();">Expand All</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Show hide regions</a>
            </p>
            <p class="bs-component">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CollapseAll();">Collapse All</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Show hide countries</a>
            </p>
        </div>
   
        </div>
<div id="header2">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>           
                <tr>
                    <td id="td1">xxxxx</td>
                    <td id="td2">xxxxx</td>
                    <td id="td3">Comment</td>
                    <td id="td4">Region</td>
                    <td id="td5" class="td5">
                        <a id="5" href="#" onclick="showDiv('5')">edit</a>
                    <span> country </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>xxxxx</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
   
    </div>
<div id="content">
   <ul id="tree">
                <li>
                    Section A
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Line Item
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                        <thead >
                                            <tr>
                                                <td id="vth1">xxxxx</td>
                                                <td id="vth2">xxxxx</td>
                                                <td id="vth3">Comment</td>
                                                <td id="vth4">Region</td>
                                                <td id="vth5" class="td5">
                                                    <a id="5" href="#" onclick="showDiv('5')">edit</a>
                                                <span> country </span>
                                                </td>                           
                                                <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="tst1" >xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td id="tdd5_1" class="td5">
                                                <input  type="checkbox" id="cb5_1" class="cbgroup5" name="cbg5[]" style="visibility:hidden"/> 
                                                <span>xxxxx</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxxndkvfkdkvkfvnk</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td id="tdd5_2" class="td5" >
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="cb5_2" class="cbgroup5" name="cbg5[]" style="visibility:hidden"/>
                                                xxxxx
                                            </td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxxfgdfgdfgfd</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td id="tdd5_3" class="td5">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="cb5_3" class="cbgroup5" name="cbg5[]" style="visibility:hidden"/>
                                                xxxxx
                                            </td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td>xxxxxfgfdgdf</td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                            <td id="tdd5_4" class="td5">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="cb5_4" class="cbgroup5" name="cbg5[]" style="visibility:hidden"/>
                                                xxxxx
                                            </td>
                                            <td>xxxxx</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

    
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just using jquery and javascript? it's pretty easy with angular. A little bit of extra worth with jquery

Comment: yeah i know , but i have to use Jquery or javascript ,,, this is the requirement , so if it is possible to set me an example , that would be perfect ,